# Is it possible and how to create independent loggers per process with log4cxx library?

Tags: c++, log4cxx

How can we have different logger ( that has independent configuration) per process when using log4cxx library?

Comment: My first thought would be launch each process with its own config file. Or you can declare multiple loggers in one config file, and have each process use a different one. Are there a few distinct processes, or one type of process which can get launched multiple times?

Comment: no, there is multiple forks of same executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`log4cxx` docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/latest_stable/usage.html), `Configuration` section shows how to configure logging by a configuration file passed as a command line arg. So basically you launch your process specifying a configuration file (different for different processes)

Comment: Actually, I need different logger per each process fork at run time